# Junit how to show details when expect error

Tags: java, jenkins, junit

My junit tests run on jenkins server with other people's.So,I always get dirty data like this:

> java.lang.Exception: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: row count (table=t_beststore_ylx_task_record) expected:<[1]> but was:<[2]>

How can I know what dirty data are?

Comment: the number of expected records do that. check your testdata, check the data you actually get returned, look for the difference

Comment: That means your actual data and your expected data is different, so that's why you getting this kind of error.

Comment: Thanks.I know that.Actually my test cases run on Jenkins server,so I need to know what the dirty data is to fix it.

Comment: `I need to know what the dirty data is to fix it`. To have a look at the failed test should provide you the information what is tested. Based on the output I would guess you expect the test to return a single row in table `t_beststore_ylx_task_record` but the thest returned two. You could amend the test to print the result just before the assert if you want to see the row content.

Comment: SubOptimal  you ard right.The dirty data from other test case,and there is a @DatabaseTearDown annotation to clear my data.So I hardly know what dirty data is via checking database.Is Junit offer methods to show error details?I hava so many junit cases,its too hard to amend all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are suffering from **other** people writing "bad" unit tests. If those people would do a better job, then your DB related tests wouldn't fail; correct?

If so - there is only one reasonable solution: each and every person who can commit tests into your bucket has to understand what they are doing.

Meaning: talk to your peers, and define clear policies, with guiding "do this, but avoid doing that" guidelines.

That is the only sane thing to do - otherwise, you step by step reduce the value that your test bucket has for you.

In other words: if you allow for **garbage** to get into your system, then **garbage** it will be what comes back to you. And I seriously doubt that the correct answer is "this is how you improve your tooling to understand the garbage coming out or your system". The answer: don't allow garbage to get into your system.

Comment: How to "don't allow garbage to get into your system"?We have many staff working on this,A small oversight cause big problem.I used  @Beforeclass to tuncate all tables before my tests.But it‘s too slow...